# What is the halacha regarding recooking livers?

Tags: halacha, meat, kashering-kosherization

Years ago, I would buy a box of raw chicken livers and roast them myself. On the box, there was a note that said that once roasted, it could not be recooked.

Recently, I found already roasted livers in my store. It's a huge convenience for me, believe me. The label on the package says that these MAY be recooked.

I'm confused. Can broiled livers be recooked or not? If they can be recooked, what conditions allow this?

Comment: Liver that was broiled to kasher it after 3 days of the animal's slaughter may still be kashered but not recooked again. Liver that was broiled soon after the slaughter (less than 3 days) may be recooked. Frozen (and when was it frozen and thawed etc) presents issues Halachically. That is the basic. I don't have the sources now.

Comment: @DavidKenner Ah! That would explain the label on the already cooked livers. (I've never recooked them, anyway, but it's good to have the option.)  When you do locate sources, please include an explanation of WHY the halacha is that way.

Comment: DanF the source for this is shulchan Aruch yoreh deah 69 12. I would encourage @David Kenner to write up a proper answer.

Comment: @user6591 https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.69.12?lang=bi&p2=Summary_of_Shakh_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.69.12.3&lang2=bi this has English

Comment: @user6591 Thanks for the source. Easy to understand.

Comment: @user6591 +1 TY

Comment: @user6591 Can you summarize and post your source as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

**Answer**

The raw chicken livers you bought were around more than 72 hours after being slaughtered, hence they could not be cooked after roasting.

The roasted livers you found in the store were roasted less than 72 hours after being slaughtered and could be recooked.

**Explanation**

<sup>As  [David Kenner](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9242/david-kenner) and [user6591](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/6591/user6591) wrote in a comment 15 months ago:</sup>

The Shulchan Aruch in [Yoreh Deah 69:12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.69.12?lang=bi&p2=Summary_of_Shakh_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.69.12.3&lang2=bi) states:

> **יב:** בָּשָׂר שֶׁשָּׁהָה ג' יָמִים מֵעֵת לְעֵת בְּלֹא מְלִיחָה, נִתְיַבֵּשׁ דָּמוֹ בְּתוֹכוֹ וְלֹא יֵצֵא עוֹד עַל יְדֵי מְלִיחָה, וְאֵין לְאָכְלוֹ  מְבֻשָּׁל, אֶלָּא צְלִי. וְאַחַר שֶׁצְּלָאוֹ  לֹא יְבַשְּׁלֶנּוּ, וְאִם בִּשְּׁלוֹ מֻתָּר. ‏
>   <sup>וְאֵין לְהַשְׁהוֹת בָּשָׂר ג' יָמִים בְּלֹא מְלִיחָה,  דְּחַיְישִׁינָן שֶׁמָּא יְבַשְּׁלוֹ (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בשם פסקי מהרא''י סימן קצ''א) .‏</sup>

Meat that wasn't kashered for 72 hours after being slaughtered has to be roasted to get rid of the blood, and kashering it by salting it isn't sufficient.

The reason being that after 72 hours the blood has congealed and salting won't remove it.

Even after it was roasted one should not cook it, though if one did so by accident then remains kosher.

As the Be'er Heitev explains, quoting the Shach:

> **מג)** **יבשלנו**. כתב הש''ך דשמא לא יצא כל דמו ע''י צליה ויצא אח''כ ע''י בישול דהבישול פועל יותר מצליה ואם בשלו מותר שאנו תולין לומר שיצא הכל ומה שנשאר ולא יצא שוב לא יצא ג''כ ע''י בישול ול''ד לכבד בר''ס ע''ג דג''כ אין לה היתר ע''י מליחה כ''א ע''י צליה ומותר לבשלה אחר הצליה אפילו לכתחלה דהתם אינו מועיל מליחה משום רבוי דם שבה ומסתמא נפלט הכל בצליה ומה שלא נפלט בצליה לא יפלוט בבישול אבל הכא אינו מועיל מליחה משום שכבר נתייבש דמו בתוכו ואפשר דצלי אינו פועל לרכך הדם שיצא הכל והבישול פועל לרככו. ‏

The reason we roast liver is because of its high blood content and kashering by salting may be insufficient to remove it all. That's why one may cook it after it was roasted.

As opposed to meat that waited 72 hours and the blood has congealed, we worry that the roasting didn't remove all the blood, and cooking may then soften and remove the leftover blood; (mixing it into your food and rendering the entire mixture unkosher).

And that's why in [73:1 - סימן עג - דין צלית הכבד](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.73.1?lang=bi&p2=Summary_of_Shakh_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.73.1&lang2=bi) - the Shulchan Aruch says that liver must first be roasted, but then can be cooked after it was roasted.

**א:** הַכָּבֵד, יֵשׁ בּוֹ רִבּוּי דָּם. לְפִיכָךְ לְכַתְּחִלָּה אֵין לוֹ  תַּקָּנָה לְבַשְּׁלוֹ עַל יְדֵי מְלִיחָה, אֶלָּא קוֹרְעוֹ שְׁתִי וָעֵרֶב וּמַנִּיחַ חִתּוּכוֹ לְמַטָּה, וְצוֹלֶהוּ שֶׁיְּהֵא רָאוּי  לַאֲכִילָה (או''ה נתיב ט''ו), וְאַחַר כָּךְ יָכוֹל לְבַשְּׁלוֹ.‏

Comment: Interesting answer. Regarding the 2nd paragraph and the Ivrit citation, it refers to "meat" in general. I'm not overly clear on the concern of recooking attached to 72 hour deadline. The Ivrit says that the only way to get out the blood is by roasting it. Fine. You did that, and the blood is removed, no? Then why is there any concern about recooking it? Is the blood out, or not?

Comment: @DanF - I quoted the Be'er Heitev explains, quoting the Shach to answer that: "We're somewhat worried that not all the blood got out, but not enough to treifen the meat if you accidentally cooked it". Kind of strange, I agree.